# try catch exception is not showing message box and catching error

Tags: vb.net

Trying to catch the exception of dividing by zero in a calculator and its not working, not sure where I am going wrong?

```
Private Sub btnEqual_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEqual.Click

    If lblOperator.Text = "+" Then
        txtAnswer.Text = Val(txtNumberOne.Text) + Val(txtNumberTwo.Text)
    ElseIf lblOperator.Text = "-" Then
        txtAnswer.Text = Val(txtNumberOne.Text) - Val(txtNumberTwo.Text)
    ElseIf lblOperator.Text = "x" Then
        txtAnswer.Text = Val(txtNumberOne.Text) * Val(txtNumberTwo.Text)
    ElseIf lblOperator.Text = "/" Then
        Try
            txtAnswer.Text = Val(txtNumberOne.Text) / Val(txtNumberTwo.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception When Val(txtNumberTwo.Text = 0)
            MessageBox.Show("You cannot divdide by zero")
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just simply check if the value is zero? Like `If Val(txtNumberTwo.Text = 0) Then MessageBox.Show("You cannot divide by zero.")`

Comment: I was trying to use a try catch statement so that I can learn how to use them but yes I could just add a conditional statement for = 0

Answer (score 0):

Division by zero with floating-point numbers returns Infinity, -Infinity or NaN instead of throwing an exception. See the documention: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx